# What version of Ruby to learn?

Tags: ruby

I've wanted to learn Ruby for some time and even started to learn a little bit. I then got distracted and for some reason went with Python. I have now however decided that even though my current project is in Python, I will also be learning Ruby and Ruby on Rails.

If somebody were to ask me what version of Python to start with I'd suggest 2.6 because 3 breaks compatibility with all the tutorials they would google. Knowing so little about Ruby, what version should I install on my computer? Is there a major difference between any two versions etc etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails recommends version 1.8.7, so if you're going to be learning rails, I'd stick with that.  This [book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby) is pretty good.

Comment: As of 2016, 1.8.7 is obsolete and only of historical interest.

Answer (score 4):

The version you learn is not that important.

While there will eventually be a shift from the more stable 1.8.x series, 1.9 isn't game breaking in a way where you will be disadvantaged.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Ruby has had that many breaking changes - except 1.9 onwards. So any version in the 1.8.x should be fine.. pick the latest stable version.
Rails on the other hand has changed dramatically in Rails 2.

Comment: Rails rate of change is my greatest love and biggest hate. I love that its growing and changing and getting new features constantly, however hate hate hate that the community often does not date or version their blogs/tutorials.

Comment: This is somewhat better now with http://guides.rubyonrails.org being very up to date.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be working in Windows, go with the current most stable one-click installer. At time of writing, that would still probably be the 1.8.6-26, although 1.8.6-27 is imminent. 1.8.7 is a small increment and I'm very uncertain about the status of 1.9.1 on the platform.

On OSX or other *nix varieties I'd be prepared to be somewhat more adventurous: the current production Rails release (2.3.2) is supposed to be 1.9.1-compatible (although that may not be the case with all third-party libraries for some time) and learning might be more entertaining with the latest version. It should run a good but faster, too.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 1.9 makes a few breaking changes, but not like Python 3. Any old Ruby tutorials should work just fine for 1.9. There's nothing like, for example, Python changing `print` and merging `range()` with `xrange()`.

It really doesn't make that much difference. The core language hasn't changed a lot — 1.9 is just a lot faster and has gained some new features.

There are some changes that broke some libraries, but those have more to do with the finer implementation details rather than what you learn in basic tutorials, so it shouldn't hurt you. If you want to go with 1.8 for the better library support, that's fine. If you want to go with 1.9 for the better core features, that's fine as well. It doesn't make that much of a difference when you're just starting off.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on building stuff that you don't release to the public, that makes use of lots of libraries, 1.8.7 or 1.8.6.  If you're writing libraries that *will* be released to the public, please, please, please make sure they work in Ruby 1.9.  Ruby 1.9 is a superior interpreter, but we're stuck with 1.8.x because so many libraries are incompatible with it right now.

http://isitruby19.com/

Answer (score 0):

Learn the latest version. Current latest version is 2.4., but when higher versions are out, go for them immediately. Ruby team pays attention to only release finished work, you don't need to be afraid to install the newest one.